# Apply transformation to PolyData

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to be able to apply tranformations to Polydata but no matter how I try to do it, it just doesn't work.

Here is what I have for "drawing" my polydata in a class call Drawing.cpp:

Drawing.h

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> clipPlane; 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImplicitPlaneRepresentation> planeRep; 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actorPlaneSource; 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> mainActor; 

vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter> transformFilter; 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> translation ; 
vtkContextView* ctxView ; 
vtkRenderWindow* win ; 
vtkRenderer* ren ; 
vtkCamera* cam ; 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> inputPolyData;
```

Then the read function is called and starts the rendering, here is the function in drawing.cpp:

```
void Drawing::read(){ 

        std::string filename = BUNNY; 
        // Read all the data from the file 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader> reader =vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader>::New(); 
        reader->SetFileName(filename.c_str()); 
        reader->Update(); 
        inputPolyData = reader->GetOutput(); 

        cout << "File Found and Loaded : " << filename << endl ; 

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> translation = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New(); 
        translation->Translate(0.3, -0.05, 0); 
        transformFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter>::New(); 
        //transformFilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort()); 
        transformFilter->SetInputData(inputPolyData); 
        transformFilter->SetTransform(translation); 
        //transformFilter->Update(); 

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New(); 
        mapper->SetInputConnection(transformFilter->GetOutputPort()); 

        mainActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New(); 
        mainActor->SetMapper(mapper); 

        ren->AddActor(mainActor); 

        vtkRenderWindowInteractor *iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New(); 
        iren->SetRenderWindow(win); 
        vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera *style = 
        vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera::New(); 
        iren->SetInteractorStyle(style); 

        //Start the event loop 
        iren->Initialize(); 
        iren->Start(); 

        defineClipping(); 
        win->PolygonSmoothingOn(); 
        win->Render(); 
        win->Start(); 
}
```

From this, I have an other thread running a server that gets messages and has a pointer to my drawing object and is supposed to call one of these three functions depending on the message it gets from its clients:

```
void Drawing::scale(float k){ 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> transform =vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New(); 
        transform->Scale(5,1,1); 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformFilter> transformFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformFilter>::New(); 
        transformFilter->SetInputConnection(cone->GetOutputPort()); 
        transformFilter->SetTransform(transform); 
        mapper->SetInputConnection(transformFilter->GetOutputPort()); 
        ren->GetActiveCamera(); 
} 

void Drawing::translate(float x, float y, float z){ 
        cout << "Translate: " << x << " - " << " - " << y << " - " << z << endl ; 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> transform1a = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New(); 
        //transform1a->Translate(x,y,z); 
        //transformFilter->SetTransform(transform1a); 
        //transformFilter->Update(); 
        double* position = mainActor->GetPosition(); 
        mainActor->SetPosition(position[0]+x,position[1]+y,position[2]+z); 
} 

void Drawing::rotate(float x, float y, float z){ 
        cout << "Rotate: " << x << " - " << " - " << y << " - " << z << endl ; 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> transform1a = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New(); 
        //transform1a->PostMultiply(); 
        //transform1a->RotateX(x); 
        //transform1a->RotateY(y); 
        //transform1a->RotateZ(z); 
        //mainActor->SetUserTransform(transform1a); 
        mainActor->RotateWXYZ(20,1,0,0); 

}
```

None of these functions work because nothing is changing in the rendering windows unless I click in the rendering window itself.
So I thought maybe I should try and add to every transformation functions: `ctxView->Render();`
But when I do I get:

> Error the ressource is already busy.

I'm a newbie in VTK but I find it weird that I can't even do a simple transformation to an object. Would really like to get some help with that.

EDIT:
Ok so after hours of trying different things I have notices that if I comment out the line `iren->Start();` my rotations and translations are called. However, the program closes as soon as there done and I cannot interact with my window anymore. Would you have some insights on that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should call only win->Render(); after your function call ...

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Let say you want to call rotate(...), so, right after this call, call win->Render();, not ctxView->Render();

Comment: Why wouldn't it work within the rotate function? Imagine my next instruction just after the last line of rotate is win->Render(), that would be exactly the same as calling it within the function wouldn't it?

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and it doesn't work either. I get the Ressource is already busy error

Comment: I'm no vtk pro either, but have you tried the other way to apply transformation on an object? Instead of using a vtkTranformationfilter, try applying directly your transformation matrix (vtkTranform) on your actor using : mainActor->SetUserTransform(translation)
keep a pointer to that vtkTranform is you want to apply other transformation

Comment: I have tried that too, also doesn't work. There seems to be a problem with the rendering

Comment: I guess that  asdfasdf are right, your transformations should be done in mapper, in such way, you get rid of these errors ...

Comment: Do you have a sample code that I could try and test to see if that work?

Comment: It would really help if you could post the smallest possible, compilable example that demonstrates the problem. Perhaps use a timer instead of your other thread to trigger the updates.

Comment: Unfortunately, it always takes a lot of code with vtk to have something working. I've tried a timer in my other thread directly and it doesn't solve the problem. I'm guessing you're thinking that threading might be the issue am I right?

Comment: I've added at the end of the read function a few calls to rotate and translate and nothing happens before I try to exit the window i.e I see all my couts done just before everything exits... I'm quite puzzled now

Comment: Are you rotating an object at the same time as interacting with the window? vtkInteractor is a blocking method as far I know, and every other actions you will do while interacting will not be done as long as you are interacting with the window

Comment: No I'm not. I have the win->start() and I just run the program without interacting at all. All I'm doing is waiting for these calls to be done and see if I get a result. But I don't unless I exit the program

Comment: people said to call ren->Render(). Can you also try ren->update() ?

Comment: the update() function does not exist for ren

Comment: See edit for more insights on what I've found so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to the help of people here and some research with the code and documentation I've figured that this part in my code was responsible for nothing happening when trying to rotate/translate/scale my Polydata:

```
//Start the event loop
iren->Initialize();
iren->Start();
```

Indeed the `start()` method of the `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` is blocking and therefore no matter what I could call afterward was not processed. Getting rid of it allows me to call my transformation functions. Yet with the loss of the possible interaction with the data and the window closing right after every transformation is applied.

Comment: Just partially solved it as I realized that the issue is actually somewhere else. i've therefore created a new post :). For further help on that matter for future users here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158342/vtkrenderwindowinteractor-event-loop-and-threading. Thanks again for helping out :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I could try to give a little code that made rotations to a polydata, but I guess that is something different from your pipeline (I am using *vtkImageReslice* object as *m_pReslice*):

```
int nExtent[3];
double dSpacing[3];
double dOrigin[3];

m_pReader->GetOutput()->GetSpacing(dSpacing);
m_pReader->GetOutput()->GetOrigin(dOrigin);
m_pReader->GetOutput()->GetDimensions(nExtent);

double dCenter[3];
dCenter[0] = dOrigin[0] + dSpacing[0] * 0.5 * nExtent[0];   // nExtent[0] is width
dCenter[1] = dOrigin[1] + dSpacing[1] * 0.5 * nExtent[1];   // nExtent[1] is height
dCenter[2] = dOrigin[2] + dSpacing[2] * 0.5 * nExtent[2];   // nExtent[2] is depth

vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> pTransform = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
pTransform->PreMultiply();

int nDirection = CDirectionDlg::GetDirection();
if(CDirectionDlg::DIR_AXIAL == nDirection)
{
    pTransform->Translate(dCenter[0], 0, dCenter[2]);
    pTransform->RotateY(180);
    pTransform->Translate(-dCenter[0], 0, -dCenter[2]);
}
else
{
    pTransform->Translate(dCenter[0], dCenter[1], 0);
    pTransform->RotateZ(180);
    pTransform->Translate(-dCenter[0], -dCenter[1], 0);
}

m_pReslice->SetResliceTransform(pTransform);
m_pReslice->SetInterpolationModeToLinear();
m_pReslice->Update();
```

Consider that another way to rotate an object in a view is to moving camera ... I hope it help you.

Comment: Unfortunately moving the camera doesn't suit my needs. I have somehow tried your solution in my above code already with the scaling function, but when I run I get an error in vtkAlgorithm.cxx... It would seem that of all the techniques I've tried so far, none works

Comment: See edit for more insights on what I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

As flaviu2 wrote, you absolutely need to call

```
ren->Render();
```

after updating your vtkTransform. Renderers do not watch VTK objects that are being rendered to see if anything has been updated. You need to call the Render() member function explicitly.

Beware threading. It is possible to use threading, but most of VTK is not thread safe, and it is probably going to cause you some headaches. To separate this problem from potential problems caused by using different threads to update objects, I would try to get this working without threading, and update this question if you still encounter problems.

Comment: Alright ! I'll try that tomorrow ( pretty late here already ! ). Will let you know ASAP

Comment: See edit for more insights on what I've found so far.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's just not clear to me what you have tried. For instance, where are these transformations you have applied in your test? Are you calling ren->Render() after each transformation. I suggest again to get a small, simple example working without threading, and if it doesn't work, post it so we can help.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. I'll post something tomorrow but so far I've seen that the problem was the interactor call to start which was blocking and therefore all the transforms were blocked too. Any way to avoid that ? Also read @asdfasdf's answer for more details

Comment: I guess that my question somehow belongs to an other question in fact. The fact that nothing happens is somehow resolved when I get rid of  the blocking start function of the window interactor. Will create a new post then and answer this one with that exact input. Thanks a lot for the help. If you have time to look at the other post please feel free to do so as I would like to get this solved somehow. Also Threading is an issue that I would like to solve but I'm guessing there are already some insights on the mailing list right?

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem is the interactor, try doing this hack. Waht it does is create a timer for the interactor that will help get out of the start blocking method :

```
class CommandSubclass2 : public vtkCommand
{
  public:
    vtkTypeMacro(CommandSubclass2, vtkCommand);

    static CommandSubclass2 *New()
    {
        return new CommandSubclass2;
    }

    void Execute(vtkObject *vtkNotUsed(caller), unsigned long vtkNotUsed(eventId), 
                    void *vtkNotUsed(callData))
    {
        std::cout << "timer callback" << std::endl;
        renderWindowInteractor->ExitCallback();
    }
};
```

// in your main

```
vtkRenderWindowInteractor *iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New(); 
iren->SetRenderWindow(win); 

iren->CreateRepeatingTimer(1);

 vtkSmartPointer<CommandSubclass2> timerCallback = 
      vtkSmartPointer<CommandSubclass2>::New();
iren->AddObserver ( vtkCommand::TimerEvent, timerCallback );

vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera *style = 
        vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera::New(); 
iren->SetInteractorStyle(style); 



while(true)
{
    iren->Start();     
    ren->Render();
}
```

Probably not the good way of doing it, but I don't know any other way to get out of the interactor blocking method `start()`

Comment: Thanks for the code I'll try it out. Is there any way for the rendering window not to disappear when everything is done and to keep on listening to events ? Cause the interactor is all I'm seeing

Comment: Ok so I've tried that and it does not solve my problem. What I want to be able to do is to have a window that I can interact with my mouse and still call those functions that will transform my polydata at the same time

Comment: I guess that my question somehow belongs to an other question in fact. The fact that nothing happens is somehow resolved when I get rid of  the blocking start function of the window interactor. Will create a new post then and answer this one with that exact input. Thanks a lot for the help. If you have time to look at the other post please feel free to do so as I would like to get this solved somehow. Also Threading is an issue that I would like to solve but I'm guessing there are already some insights on the mailing list right?