# vtkRenderWindowInteractor event loop and threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, vtk

What I am trying to do in an application using vtk for both interacting and rendering is to have two different parts:
1 - A thread with Rendering and vtkRenderWindowInteractor for interaction with mouse.
2 - A thread that call some modifier functions of the data defined in the VTK Thread.

From what I've gotten so far in my research it seems rather complicated and VTK is not thread safe. Now I've stumbled upon this post (http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Multi-threaded-VTK-td4514620.html) on the VTK mailing list that suggests using Qt Signals and Slots. A first question would be is that still the good solution?

A second question which is still linked to that and to a problem that I've encountered before is that the `start()`of the `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` is blocking. And so far, no matter what I've tried all the modification done by rotation or translation or scaling functions are not done as long as the start() method is called (because I enter a rendering loop).
My question would then be: If I use Qt Signals and Slots will that prevent me from that problem?

Here is the basic code that I have so far for rendering and lauching the vtkRenderWindowInteractor:

```
std::string filename = BUNNY;
// Read all the data from the file
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader> reader =vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
reader->Update();
inputPolyData = reader->GetOutput();

cout << "File Found and Loaded : " << filename << endl ;

vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> translation = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
translation->Translate(0.3, -0.05, 0);
transformFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter>::New();
//transformFilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
transformFilter->SetInputData(inputPolyData);
transformFilter->SetTransform(translation);
//transformFilter->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(transformFilter->GetOutputPort());

mainActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
mainActor->SetMapper(mapper);

ren->AddActor(mainActor);

vtkRenderWindowInteractor *iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
iren->SetRenderWindow(win);
vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera *style =
vtkInteractorStyleMultiTouchCamera::New();
iren->SetInteractorStyle(style);

//Start the event loop
iren->Initialize();
iren->Start();

//defineClipping();
win->PolygonSmoothingOn();
win->Render();
win->Start();

ctxView->Render();
```

So that I could sum it up by asking: will Qt allow me to have to call transforming functions while the rendering and interacting thread of vtk is running with the blocking `start()` method of `vtkRenderWindowInteractor`? If not should I change my code and think about different possibilities for interacting with my objects in VTK?

Comment: As you read yourself, the VTK is not thread safe, so why are you using transformation in another thread then main ? I don't think it's worth it ... as you see, that is bring you a lot of headache ... Put all yours stuffs (render and transformations, ok, put a wait cursor where transformations take long), and you'll get rid of lot of trouble !

Comment: The thing is what I need to design needs to support this. I cannot do otherwise. I have all my rendering and transformation functions in one class but I need to be able to call them from an other thread ( here a server ). But I've read that using Qt signals and slots could save me a lot of pain for that matter. Just don't know if that's really the case and if anyone has tried that before. Besides it does not solve the problem of the start() method which is blocking anyway

Comment: I do not know Qt at all (MFC has class to thread synchronize as well), but I am thinking that I would do this task in following way: I would create a flag that tell me when the rendering has complete, and only this flag tell me that rendering has done, I would do the transformation task ... after that, of course, I would send a rendering message to render the view ... sorry if I didn't understand well your issue ...

Comment: Well my problem is that I still have a server which is in a different thread and it will be thing calling those transformation functions

Comment: Well, might not understand your issue, but as long as you know when your server is sending you the signal to apply the transformations, so, do the transformations, and ONLY AFTER that, call rendering ... is this the way of doing now ?

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do in my previous post. My server gets a message, from that message derives the appropriate data for the transformation, call that transformation function and at the end of the transformation function I call the Render() function. It gives me no result because of the loop of the start() function from vtkRenderWindowInteractor and it gives me an error stating that the ressource is already busy (probably because of the blocking function again). So my problem truely is that blocking start() function. I'm guessing the threading is not that complicated afterwards...

Comment: I guess the architecture of your app is not so happy ... I should leave the office now, see you tomorrow. Bye.

Comment: I'm open for an other architecture but right now what I have is like: a server running in one thread the rendering on my main thread. My server gets a pointer to the class handling the rendering. Whenever it gets a new message with transformation informations it calls the appropriate function from the rendering class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been able to do rotations after calling `start()`, but in my case from the same thread.

The trick is to use a `vtkCommand` and set a timer in the `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` to call that command. That command is basically a callback that will be able to modify your actors.

You can see a working example of this in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075569/vtk-rotate-actor-programmatically-while-vtkrenderwindowinteractor-is-active).

Regarding the multi-threading approach you're using, maybe you could keep the rendering thread waiting in `vtkCommand::Execute` until the modifying thread is done. If you're able to use C++11 you could use a lot of the new tools available in the STL.

Comment: I think I can use it yes. What kind of tools would be good then? Can you give some insights on that ? Your answer is really helpful yet it does not completely solve my problem (that's why I upvoted both your answer and your post which is also interesting and partially answering and well explained) because calling something with a timer does not solve the fact that it should answer to functions calls from my server when it gets a message

Comment: My experience with threading is within the same process. From your text, I don't know if that's your case, or if you need to pass a message through a local network, or what. That should influence your design enough for a generic answer not to be that useful. If it's within the same thread, `std::thread`, `std::condition_variable` should be useful. If not, try looking into `std::future` and `std::async`.

Comment: No I'm not using a local network at all. I have a program with two different threads. One is the server listening for messages from a remote client and the other one is the rendering. So I guess I'm in the same case as you are right? :)

Comment: I gave up on the idea of using an other thread. Thanks for the answer ;)