# How do I make a custom event with VTK?

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm making a thread software with VTK, where I need to change the model itself in real time, while I need to change his method of rendering. Everything is working fine, but, the problem start with the `interactor->start();` , the model data gets updated just fine, but it's only showed on screen when I move The camera. Also I have selected some methods for generating a 3D data from a imagedata file, for that I need to close the vtk window (interactor window) and then the code will reopen it and send the new data generated to it...

I would need something like these:

```
int force close_window = false; int refresh_interactor = false;
```

I managed to make the Window close, but only with `vtkcommand::Keypressed` command, but idk how do I do with a new command :S, I tried the `vtkcommand::UserEvent` but I didn't found a good information about how to deal with that data (like some way to call it)

the way I'm dealing with VTK is with two threads, the first one, is just about the vtk iren loop, and the second one would manage the models and check if iren requires to be updated.

In my dream code it should be something like this:

=======================================================

```
bool VTKWindow()
{ 
    ... 
    vtkSmartPointer ator = vtkSmartPointer::New(); 
    iren = vtkSmartPointer::New(); 
    RenWindow = vtkSmartPointer::New(); 
    render->SetBackground(.1, .2, .3); 
    RenWindow->AddRenderer(renderer); 
    iren->SetRenderWindow(RenWindow);

    if(data_type == voxel_type)
    { 
        Render->AddViewProp(VoxelData); 
    }
    else
    { 
        actor->SetMapper(PolyData);
        Render->AddActor(Actor); 
    }

    RenWindow->Render(); 
    iren->Start();
}

void ManageVTK()
{ 
    while true loop... 
            if(force close_window == true)
                do some command to exit the iren loop 
            if(refresh_interactor == true)
                do some command to refresh iren 
}
```

Sorry for the english, it's not my native language, and also sorry about the question format, it's the first time I'm using stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

It may sounds stupid, but, I found a kind of solution for the problem.
 I saw on related links this guy [vtkRenderWindowInteractor event loop and threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158342/vtkrenderwindowinteractor-event-loop-and-threading?rq=1) and, it's almost the same problem...

```
class VTKNewEvent : public vtkCommand{
    public:
        vtkTypeMacro(VTKNewEvent , vtkCommand);

        static VTKNewEvent * New(){
            return new VTKNewEvent ;
        }
        void Execute(vtkObject * caller, unsigned long vtkNotUsed(eventId), void * vtkNotUsed(callData)){
            vtkRenderWindowInteractor *iren = static_cast<vtkRenderWindowInteractor*>(caller);
            if (iren_close == true){
                iren->GetRenderWindow()->Finalize                   // Stop the interactor
                iren->TerminateApp();
                iren_close = false;
            }
            if (iren_update== true){
                renderJanela->Render();
                iren_update= false;
            }           
        }
};


bool VTKWindow(){
    vtkSmartPointer<VTKNewEvent > IrenRefresh= vtkSmartPointer<VTKNewEvent>::New();
...
    iren->CreateRepeatingTimer(1);//this makes that IrenRefresh will be called at every 1ms
    iren->AddObserver(vtkCommand::TimerEvent, IrenRefresh);
    iren->Start();
...
}
```

it's simple, but, maybe not the best, but it did Th job, I hope this link will help people that are starting into the VTK world, since threads + rendering loop wasn't a simple job to understand what was going on

Comment: I'm not sure if you really created a new event in this code. Because you're using the `vtkCommand::TimerEvent` as the event that triggers the observer. The right way to create a new event is using the `vtkCommand::UserEvent + intShift`, where _intShift_ is a integer that will allow to create more new events. One can register these new events updating vtkAllEventsMacro. In this [example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/UserEvent), the file **vtkTestFilter.h** shows how to create a new event without registering it.